# hidden field not working in zend form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, hidden-field

I have a "date_created" field in database and I want to make it hidden in form and current date add in mysql table.
I am working in zend form and below code for date_created element is not working.

```
$date = date('Y/m/d h:i:s ', time());

$form->addElement('hidden', 'date_created', array(
        'decorators'    => array('ViewHelper'),
        'multioptions'   => array(
                        $date
                        ),
        ));
```

edited for formatting

Comment: try changing 'multioptions' = ... to 'value' = $date

Comment: how are you getting the data out of the form and into the db?

Comment: Well I have 1 more doubt the date is current but time it's not matching with my time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you passing multioptions to an hidden field ?

It's :

```
$form->addElement('hidden', 'date_created', array(
    'decorators' => array('ViewHelper'),
    'value'      => $date
));
```

Comment: well i tried this also but still in db it's taking 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: How are you getting the value ?

Comment: Well I have 1 more doubt the date is current but time it's not matching with my time

Comment: @VinodHC -- It's probably showing you the time on the server.